# Network pre requisite using ec2 command line

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to find out the pre requisite for using ec2 command line - network aspect.
I know it requires some kind of network access - when my machine had issues with its NAT configuration the CLI did not work. 
I want specific details to make sure we set the right and minimal configuration.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CLI calls AWS web-services APIs. So make sure you have out going internet access on standard webservice port 80/443. That should good enough for you to get started.

Comment: This I got. I am looking for more specific details so my network configuration will be as strict as possible.

Comment: Could you post your "specific" questions so that we can get you the relevant answer. At the moment, you have not specified what exactly are you thinking of OR what exact information are you looking for.

Comment: I don't want my servers to have internet access to all sites. I want to know what to set in my firewall. Yes I can use a sniffer but I was surprise that I did not find any documentation about it. Maybe I am missing something but my site is already in amazon. Why use the internet? I would expect some kind of an internal address and have it well documented. I hope I was able to explain myself this time...

Comment: AWS APIs are served over the [Regions and Endpoint URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) which are exposed over the internet. I am not aware any "internal" way of accessing these APIs. Try posting your queries on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30) where one of Amazonians might get you a better suggestion.